# How to include images as a resource into C++ executable?

Tags: c++, image, compilation

My images should be present at the directory of my .exe file to show up in the program and also they are accessible before running the program.

Is there a function to include images as resources with the code to compile them as one single executable file? Is there any way?

Comment: fwiw pack into executable doesn't prevent unpack.

Comment: @appleapple True, but not everyone knows how to unpack.

Comment: There are some tools that de-compile a binary file into a C++ array initialization `const char image[] = { 0x01, 0x02, ... }`. Is that workable for you?